# Update query does not affect any rows, privileges are set to public and allow all actions

Tags: postgresql, spatial-database, update, pgadmin-3, administrative-boundaries

I've been trying to update a column of integers called level_dept in a table called adminboundaries within the sql query tool on pgadmin3 and the query runs and finishes with a lot of lag, but 0 rows are affected. I didn't receive any syntax errors and I've set the privileges to allows the user role to perform all actions, are there any other particular settings or things I should check that I should know about?

```
BEGIN;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
UPDATE AdminBoundaries
SET "LEVEL_DEPT" = "LEVEL_DEPT" - 1
WHERE "NAME_3" = NULL AND "LEVEL_DEPT" = 3; 
COMMIT;
```

Error Log:

```
2013-01-03 15:58:03 EST STATEMENT:  BEGIN;
    EXPLAIN ANALYZE
    UPDATE AdminBoundaries
    SET "LEVEL_DEPT" = "LEVEL_DEPT" - 1
    WHERE "NAME_3" = NULL AND "LEVEL_DEPT" = 3; 
    COMMIT;
```

Despite trying a few variations of syntax, I think it might be a pgadmin related issue? I'm not sure though. I'm considering changing the postgresql.conf file. I've already enabled seq_scan to be off. There are other parameters I'm considering changing.

Is it necessary to look into the nuances of postgresql as far as dirty reads, commit delays, etc when processing in a table of only 250k rows?

Comment: I have tried running a select statement using your where clause?  Do you get any results?

Comment: yes I do get results from my select statement.

Comment: needs COMMIT; command http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/sql-commit.html

Comment: didn't work. command has been edited. The message was:Query result with 8 rows discarded.


Query returned successfully with no result in 14 ms.

Comment: shouldn't it work without the EXPLAIN ANALYZE part

Comment: nope, I'll put up the log.

Comment: try UPDATE AdminBoundaries
    SET "LEVEL_DEPT" = "LEVEL_DEPT" - 1
    WHERE "NAME_3" IS NULL AND "LEVEL_DEPT" = 3;

Comment: I've tried that. I think actually I am going to try the many variations again after enabling either synchronous commit or fsync on the backend configuration editor because according to the link below, fsync needs to be enabled to write to disk.  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-wal.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `"NAME_3" = NULL`, since NULL is not "equal to" NULL. This should instead use the proper SQL construct `"NAME_3" IS NULL`. See [the documentation for more details](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html).

Comment: I've actually tried that, it still didn't give me any results. But, is it supposed to? It gave me:Query result with 5 rows discarded.
Query returned successfully with no result in 16 ms.
Yet, I'm not discarding anything here...